# Drawing my own title bar

Tags: winforms, c#-3.0, dllimport

I'm drawing part of the title bar in my WinForm applications. Is working Ok (placing the name of the company centered and in Orange)

[image]

This is the code to do that at the form code:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;


  [DllImport("user32.dll")]
  private static extern IntPtr GetWindowDC(IntPtr hWnd);

  [DllImport("user32.dll")]
  private static extern int ReleaseDC(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hDC);



  private Rectangle PosicionTexto()
  {
     string sTexto = String.Format("{0} : {1}", this.Text, "Trevo I.T.");
     sTexto = "Trevo I.T.";

     Graphics oG = this.CreateGraphics();

     SizeF oS = oG.MeasureString(sTexto, new Font("Tahoma", 8f, FontStyle.Bold));

     Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
     rect.X = (this.Width/2) - (int)(oS.Width/2);
     rect.Y = SystemInformation.FrameBorderSize.Height + 4;
     rect.Width = (int)oS.Width;
     rect.Height = SystemInformation.CaptionButtonSize.Height;

     return rect;
  }

  private void DrawTitleBar(IntPtr hwnd)
  {
     // Obtenemos el Canvas a partir del DC de la ventana
     IntPtr hdc = GetWindowDC(hwnd);
     Graphics gBarra = Graphics.FromHdc(hdc);

     Rectangle rect = PosicionTexto();
     string sTexto = String.Format("{0} : {1}", this.Text, "Trevo I.T.");
     sTexto = "Trevo I.T.";
     gBarra.DrawString(sTexto, new Font("Tahoma", 8f, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Orange, new PointF(rect.X, rect.Y));

     // Liberamos la memoria*/
     gBarra.Flush();
     ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdc);
  }

  protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
  {
     switch (m.Msg)
     {
        case 0x000F: // WM_PAINT
        case 0x0085: // WM_NCPAINT:
           base.WndProc(ref m);
           DrawTitleBar(m.HWnd);
           break;

        default:
           // Invocamos a la funcion original
           base.WndProc(ref m);
           break;
     }
  }
```

The issue is resizing the window. The text is not cleared and shown several times. Is there a way to "Refresh" the title bar before drawing my text?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**
Almost solved. Added two more methods:

```
  // Rectangle of the title bar
  private Rectangle TitleBarRectangle()
      {
         Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
         rect.X = 1 + SystemInformation.CaptionButtonSize.Width;  // Avoid to draw over the icon
         rect.Y = 1;
         rect.Width = Width - (SystemInformation.CaptionButtonSize.Width * 4); // Avoid to draw over the buttons
         rect.Height = SystemInformation.CaptionButtonSize.Height;
         return rect;
      }

  // Draw a filled rectangle
  private void ClearTitleBar(IntPtr hwnd)
  {
     // Obtenemos el Canvas a partir del DC de la ventana
     IntPtr hdc = GetWindowDC(hwnd);

     try
     {
        using (Graphics gBarra = Graphics.FromHdc(hdc))
        {
           Rectangle rect = TitleBarRectangle();
           gBarra.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(SystemColors.ActiveCaption), rect);
           gBarra.Flush();
        }
     }
     finally
     {
        ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdc);
     }
  }
```

and modified one:

```
  protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
  {
     switch (m.Msg)
     {
        case 0x0085: // WM_NCPAINT:
        case 0x0005: // WM_SIZE
           base.WndProc(ref m);
           DrawTitleBar(m.HWnd);
           break;

        case 0x214:  //   WM_SIZING 
           base.WndProc(ref m);
           ClearTitleBar(m.HWnd);
           break;

        default:
           // Invocamos a la funcion original
           base.WndProc(ref m);
           break;
     }
  }
```

By the way, the whole idea started from [Copstone](http://copstone.com/2010/02/agregando-botones-a-la-barra-de-titulo-de-una-ventana/)

Thanks Lars, Zach and of course, Jim. Your comments and answers put me on the way.

Comment: Even if you solve this problem, I don't think it will even paint in Vista or Win7 because of the Aero UI.

Comment: @LarsTech. Thanks for your comment. I'm "still" in XP. Probably, when I migrate to W7, will check the OS version and disable this functionality or try to solve it then. By now, I'm trying everything but nothing is not working. :(

Comment: I'd recommend using or deriving the color from one of the system colors instead of using a hardcoded color like orange.  System and theme colors can change from OS to OS and from user to user, so using one hardcoded color is very likely make your program feel out of place on systems with different colors than the one you developed it on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution is to call `gBarra.FillRectangle` to fill the title bar with the background color before you draw the string.

Are you sure you need to do this in WM_PAINT? Seems like WM_NCPAINT would be enough.

I strongly recommend that you use `try...finally` to ensure that the DC gets released. That is:

```
private void DrawTitleBar(IntPtr hwnd)
{
     // Obtenemos el Canvas a partir del DC de la ventana
     IntPtr hdc = GetWindowDC(hwnd);
     try
     {
         using (Graphics gBarra = Graphics.FromHdc(hdc))
         {
             Rectangle rect = PosicionTexto();
             string sTexto = String.Format("{0} : {1}", this.Text, "Trevo I.T.");
             sTexto = "Trevo I.T.";
             gBarra.DrawString(sTexto, new Font("Tahoma", 8f, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Orange, new PointF(rect.X, rect.Y));

             // Liberamos la memoria*/
             gBarra.Flush();
         }   
     }
     finally
     {
         ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdc);
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. U r totally right. I have to use try... finally, and just WM_NCPAINT. The problem I see with filling the rectangle with the background color is, that I don't know that color. Also have to catch WM_RESIZING (I think) to do that. Mmmm. I will try it and let you know. Thanks again

Comment: @Nane SystemColors.ActiveCaption and SystemColors.InactiveCaption are the colors I think you are looking for.

Comment: BTW, your example code is leaking the Font resource that you create.

Comment: Even this is draft code, I appreciate the advice's. Just learning... or trying ;)