# How to change the text style of the WinForm Title?

Tags: c#, winforms

All, Is there any possibility to change the text style of the WinForm Title? for example I want to set the form title text to **bold**. I tried `Font` attribute of `Form` . but it only apply to the content of the `Form`. Thanks.

Comment: This sounds simple but not really. You have to do some `non-client area painting`. In `aero system`, you may have to extend the glassy area into client and set the client size to the bound size. Another solution is customize your own window caption.

Comment: Could someone who downvote it please tell me the reason for doing that ? thanks.

Comment: Not sure about the downvote, I'll fix it for you. If you want to change the TitleBar of a winform you'll probably have to draw it yourself, I think thats the reason for the downvote. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312978/drawing-my-own-title-bar

Comment: @JeremyThompson +1 Thanks your help. It sounds simple but not easy to work it out . :) I will try it .

Comment: If this is just for visual effects while the form is being viewed you have the option of FormBorderStyle = none and then place whatever you'd like in the title position. Note that the "real" text title is still used by the system to identify the window.