# Is it possible that I can draw the Form window title text by myself?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want to draw the Winform **title text** . Is there any can do it?

Only the title text.

I also find out there is a way to Draw all title : [Drawing my own title bar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8312978/1900498), But the code is very confuse me, It's not like a Form, and I only need to re-draw the title text.

Sorry for the short question.

---

**Update:**

I'm using Krypton Toolkit for the Form window skin now. That's why I only want to draw the title text but keep the other skin and style.

Answer (score 1):

You can't owner-draw **only** the title text. You either draw the whole title bar (although it's more typical to just hide it and draw a custom component with a title bar and handle the moving/resizing), or let Windows draw it, but you can't *just* change the way the string with the title is drawn.

You could draw a title bar exactly like Windows does (and then draw the title text as you wanted), but it involves tons of API calls to get the metrics and colors and it's definitely not easy if you want to support several Windows versions (even Microsoft [doesn't get it right](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1059444/in-windows-8-drawtobitmap-on-a-form-draws-the-windows-7-chrome) all the time!)

You can also use this ([Custom Window Frame Using DWM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb688195%28VS.85%29.aspx)) through P/Invoke, and set the form text to nothing, then draw whatever you want on the non-client area... that's how Office does it, but again, it's a lot of pain for possibly not much gain.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible. Look at this code here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42223/Easy-Customize-Title-Bar